# how do i write/convert this in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

How to write/convert below `Kotlin` code to `Java`. I have implemented a `Kotlin` library which is completely written in `Kotlin`

The library uses this code as callback. I need help on how I can call it from `Java` class.

```
timelinePicker.setOnSelectedTimeRangeChangedListener { from, to ->
        selectedTimeTextView.text = getString(R.string.from_to, from.format(), to.format())
    }
```

Comment: should be a simple translation to  a [Java lambda](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).

Comment: could not find a converter in provided link. will you please do it for me?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of StackOverflow. This is not a side where you post a problem and get code in return. The link I provided should provide you with all necessary information to do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timelinePicker.setOnSelectedTimeRangeChangedListener((from, to) -> {
    selectedTimeTextView.setText(getString(R.string.from_to, from.format(), to.format()));
});
```